# Can't connect to Battlenet gateways in Starcraft Remastered (both Crossover and Lutris)

Tags: linux, networking, wine, games

I am having trouble running Starcraft Remastered on Linux. I have a dual boot laptop (Windows 10 and Manjaro) that has NVIDIA Optimus, and I use Prime Render Offloading. I am using Linux kernel 5.12.9-1. I recently updated my system with 'pamac -S update'. I usually use Crossover to play Starcraft Remastered on Linux.

However, ever since the last Starcraft Remastered update, I have been unable to connect to any Battle.net gateways on Starcraft Remastered. I don't even see the gateways as that entire section is empty. I can click on the Ok button, and it supposedly connects me to a gateway, but then I can't join any games. I can't see the names of the games or any of the messages in the chat. Again, it's totally empty. I can play in Windows 10, but I much prefer to spend the majority of my time in Linux. I had this problem previously (the second to the last update to Starcraft Remastered), but installing Korean and then uninstalling it worked. This time, that didn't work for me.

Things I have already tried but didn't work:

- I copied the Starcraft folder as well as the Battle.net folder to the respective folders in Crossover (/home/gameofdronez/.cxoffice/Battle.net_Desktop_App/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/)
- I installed Lutris and installed Starcraft Remastered. I also tried various profiles other than Starcraft Remastered (Overwatch, Starcraft II, and Blizzard Battle.net). I even tried various Wine staging versions including 5.0, nfsworld-5.4, 5.7-11, and 6.10-5.
- I ran 32 bit client instead of 64 bit client, in both Crossover and Lutris.
- I installed Korean and then uninstalled Korean.
- Ran the 32 bit client in Windows. Then switched to Linux, uninstalled Starcraft in Lutris, copied the Starcraft folder from my Windows drive to the respective folder in Lutris, opened the Blizzard Battle.net app through Lutris, chose the Starcraft folder to install from (where Lutris stores games), and then launched the 32 bit client through Lutris.

Does anyone have other ideas I can try?

Comment: Just here to tell you I have the same problem and haven't been able to fix it either.